# change margin-top on scroll (animate)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

Thanks to user Rex, I now use the following code to change the margin on scroll with an animation effect.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
$("#content").animate({margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"}, 3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/qSe4e/10/

Now I would like to have the same effect when I scroll up that the margin goes back to it's original state, I tried it with the following script that detects an up or down scroll but it doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/14 *(the alert messages helped me to show me if the scroll detection script worked)*

hopefully someone can help me

**SOLUTION:**

http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

This answer refers to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qSe4e/14

**End edit.**

In the jsfiddle, you are registering a handler for the window's scroll event that says, "when the window scrolls, register a handler for the document scroll event" which is messing everything up.  So your code that looks like this:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
  $("#three").animate({margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"}, 3000);
});
```

Should really just be this:

```
$("#three").animate({margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"}, 3000);
```

Basically just remove the document scroll wrapper.

Then, there's a second problem in that jQuery is automatically queueing those animations for you so they will be delayed as you scroll around.  You'll get a better result with something like this:

```
$("#three").animate({margin: "0px 0px 0px 0px"}, {queue: false, duration: 3000});
```

Make those changes in your fiddle and see what you get.